# undefined local variable or method 'book'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and trying to create a sample app. I have

App/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
     resources :books do
        book.resources :comments, :only => :create
     #root 'books#index'
end
end
```

Not sure why I am getting the following error

```
/bookshelf/config/routes.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `book' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fdebb03e728> (NameError)
```

Comment: Remove `book.` from the third line. Your route block should look like `resources :books do
        resources :comments, :only => :create
end`

Comment: Thanks. When i removed book. and loaded application it went to rails page "you are rails" didnt load the application

Comment: Maybe you're seeing the default root page. Try to hit `/books` or create a root route in your `routes.rb` like `root 'books#index'`.

Comment: Thing is i am getting that error when i am starting server

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: Thanks it works. when i hit with /books

Answer (score 3):

Remove "book."

It should look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  resources :books do
    resources :comments, only: :create
  end
end
```